# Polymer 1.0 Dom-if check with attribute

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to show template according to the attribute passed in the element.

Say

```
 <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[!multiLine]]">
        ..
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[multiLine]]">
        ..
    </template>
</template>
```

in properties I pass

```
properties:{
   multiLine: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
    }
}
```

and in the html I can only pass **multi-line** as attribute.
How can I achieve this? Its always going in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `multi-line` attribute in the element outside of a `dom-bind` template, it would always evaluate to `true`, regardless of the value you passed, though you can set it to `false` by not adding the attribute at all on the element or by setting it with a falsy value in js.